# Removing spaces in MaskedTextBox on Leave Event - IP Address Validation

Tags: c#, validation, ip-address, keypress, maskedtextbox

I'm trying to do IPv4 validation in a maskedtextbox. My mask is set to ###.###.###.### and i have my Key Down Event handling the '.' key as going to next octet which works great... However, if an IP address dows not have 3 digits in each octet i get random spaces when I grab the textfield for use.

For example: if I type 72.13.12.1 the output is "72 .13 .12 .1" <- I don't want the spaces.

I've tried doing some validation like removing the spaces once I leave the maskedtextbox, but if I remove the spaces, my mask kicks back in and changes it to "721.321.1  ."

```
this.maskedTextBoxExternIP.ResetOnSpace = false;
this.maskedTextBoxExternIP.SkipLiterals = false;
this.maskedTextBoxExternIP.PromptChar = ' ';
this.maskedTextBoxExternIP.Mask = "###.###.###.###";
this.maskedTextBoxExternIP.ValidatingType = typeof(System.Net.IPAddress);
this.maskedTextBoxExternIP.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.maskedTextBoxExternIP_KeyDown);
this.maskedTextBoxExternIP.Enter += new EventHandler(this.maskedTextBoxExternIP_Enter);
this.maskedTextBoxExternIP.Leave += new EventHandler(this.maskedTextBoxExternIP_Leave);

        private void maskedTextBoxExternIP_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Resets the cursor when we leave the textbox  
            maskedTextBoxExternIP.SelectionStart = 0;
            // Enable the TabStop property so we can cycle through the form controls again  
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                c.TabStop = true;
            IPAddress ipAddress;
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(maskedTextBoxExternIP.Text, out ipAddress))
            {
                //valid ip
            }
            else
            {
                //is not valid ip
                maskedTextBoxExternIP.Text = maskedTextBoxExternIP.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            }
        }
        // Handle the Enter event  
        private void maskedTextBoxExternIP_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Resets the cursor when we enter the textbox  
            maskedTextBoxExternIP.SelectionStart = 0;
            // Disable the TabStop property to prevent the form and its controls to catch the Tab key  
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                c.TabStop = false;
        }
        // Handle the KeyDown event  
        private void maskedTextBoxExternIP_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // Cycle through the mask fields  
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab || e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod || e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
            {
                int pos = maskedTextBoxExternIP.SelectionStart;
                int max = (maskedTextBoxExternIP.MaskedTextProvider.Length - maskedTextBoxExternIP.MaskedTextProvider.EditPositionCount);
                int nextField = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < maskedTextBoxExternIP.MaskedTextProvider.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!maskedTextBoxExternIP.MaskedTextProvider.IsEditPosition(i) && (pos + max) >= i)
                        nextField = i;
                }
                nextField += 1;

                // We're done, enable the TabStop property again  
                if (pos == nextField)
                    maskedTextBoxExternIP_Leave(this, e);

                maskedTextBoxExternIP.SelectionStart = nextField;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Windows Common Controls library includes and IP address control but there's no WinForms version of it. See if [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9352/A-C-IP-Address-Control) helps.

Comment: @madreflection I've used this in the past, but I dont want my .exe to be dependent on the DLL. is there anything to do about this?

Comment: You could use ILMerge to combine it with your application.

Comment: What exactly is your concern? Having another DLL file with your executable? Depending on something you didn't write?

Comment: The concern is with storing it on the machine. I want to be able to deploy the executable to other PCs without having to map the DLL or have it in the folder. Ill look into ILmerge thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@madreflection I finally got the [IPAddressCrontrolLib](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9352/A-C-IP-Address-Control) to work I just used the source files and embedded the library that way. Had to do a little fudging around to clear all the errors that we there. All good now! Just needed a new day to get through that one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I mentioned the source code but deleted the comment. IANAL so I didn't want to suggest doing something that might violate the license attached to it.